# Magento 2 : Change Render Value for Grid in Custom Backend Module

Tags: magento2, admin, grid

I want change text value on my grid custom module, in database I just allowed to save 0 or 1 but in grid I want change and show that value from 1/0 to be Yes/No,

[image]

here is my grid layout xml code :

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"       xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="KS\Brand\Block\Adminhtml\Items" name="adminhtml.block.promo.quote.grid.container">
            <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid" name="adminhtml.block.promo.quote.grid" as="grid">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">ks_brand_items_grid</argument>
                    <argument name="dataSource" xsi:type="object">KS\Brand\Model\Resource\Items\Collection</argument>
                    <argument name="default_sort" xsi:type="string">sort_order</argument>
                    <argument name="default_dir" xsi:type="string">ASC</argument>
                    <argument name="save_parameters_in_session" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
                </arguments>
                <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\ColumnSet" as="grid.columnSet" name="adminhtml.promo.quote.grid.columnSet">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="rowUrl" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="path" xsi:type="string">ks_brand/*/edit</item>
                            <item name="extraParamsTemplate" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="id" xsi:type="string">getId</item>
                            </item>
                        </argument>
                    </arguments>
                    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="id">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</argument>
                            <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
                            <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-id</argument>
                            <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-id</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="name">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Name</argument>
                            <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">name</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                     <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="gateway">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Gateway</argument>
                            <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">gateway</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="is_enable">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Is Enable</argument>
                            <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">is_enable</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="storefront">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Storefront</argument>
                            <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">storefront</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>

                </block>
            </block>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add following line inside your column

```
<argument name="type" xsi:type="string">options</argument>
<argument name="options" xsi:type="options" model="KS\Brand\Model\Source\Status"/>
```

Now create **KS\Brand\Model\Source\Status.php**

```
namespace KS\Brand\Model\Source;

class Status implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{
    /**
     * Change 0,1 to No,Yes.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return [
            ['value' => 0, 'label' => __('No')],
            ['value' => 1, 'label' => __('Yes')]
        ];
    }
}
```

Clear cache.

[Check more detail](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/Integration/view/adminhtml/layout/adminhtml_integration_grid_block.xml#L41)

Comment: hi @Sohel Rana , I have follow link and I get error :

`1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Vendor\Module\Model\source\Status does not exist`

Comment: In your case 'Vendor\Module' should be 'KS\Brand'.

Comment: Check updated answer, I just changed.

Comment: sorry for late reply, I got a lot of rest on the last two days....I have tried your edited code and this work, thank you very much.

Comment: can you please helped me multi selected value  label in magento2 admin grid https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/295585/how-to-show-a-label-in-admin-grid-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to render data from database and display in admin grid, then you need to follow these:

i. in Grid.php :

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
{
  ....
  $this->addColumn(
            'certification_body',
            [
                'header' => __('Certification Body'),
                'index' => 'certification_body',
                'class' => 'certification_body',
                'renderer' => 'Prithweema\CertificateBody\Block\Adminhtml\Certificatebody\Edit\Tab\Renderer\CertificateBody'
            ]
        );
  ....
  ....
}
```

ii. in your renderer file(Prithweema/CertificateBody/Block/Adminhtml/Certificatebody/Edit/Tab/Renderer/CertificateBody.php) :

```
<?php

namespace Prithweema\CertificateBody\Block\Adminhtml\Certificatebody\Edit\Tab\Renderer;

use Magento\Framework\DataObject;

class CertificateBody extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\AbstractRenderer
{
    public function render(DataObject $row)
    {
        $value = $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex());
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $body = $objectManager->get('Prithweema\CertificateBody\Model\Certificatebody')->load($value);
        return $body->getCertificateBody();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think use objectManager is not good idea, but I feel this will be useful for reference. I will vote up. thanks :)

Comment: Do not use object Manager(Magneto 2 discourage its usage), use Repositories or factories instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php


namespace Vendor\CustomReview\Block\Adminhtml\Customer\Grid\Renderer;

use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\AbstractRenderer;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class CustomerEmails extends AbstractRenderer
{
    /**
     * @var CustomerRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $customerRepository;
    /**
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    private $storeManager;

    /**
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
     */
    public function __construct(StoreManagerInterface $storeManager, CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository)
    {
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    public function render(DataObject $row)
    {

        $customerId = $row->getData();
        print_r($customerId);
//        die();
        $customerEmail = '';
        if($customerId['customer_id']){
            $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId['customer_id']);
            $customerEmail = $customer->getEmail();
        }

        return $customerEmail;
    }
}

review_listing.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="review_columns" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
        <column name="customer_id" sortOrder="90">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">Customer Emails</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

\Vendor\CustomReviews\Block\Adminhtml\Customer\Grid\Renderer\CustomerEmails

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);


namespace Vendor\CustomReview\Block\Adminhtml;

class Grid extends \Magento\Review\Block\Adminhtml\Grid
{

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper,
        \Magento\Review\Model\ReviewFactory $reviewFactory,
        \Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\Product\CollectionFactory $productsFactory,
        \Magento\Review\Helper\Data $reviewData,
        \Magento\Review\Helper\Action\Pager $reviewActionPager,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry, array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $backendHelper,
            $reviewFactory,
            $productsFactory,
            $reviewData,
            $reviewActionPager,
            $coreRegistry,
            $data);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare grid columns
     *
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn(
            'review_id',
            [
                'header' => __('ID'),
                'filter_index' => 'rt.review_id',
                'index' => 'review_id',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-id',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-id'
            ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'created_at',
            [
                'header' => __('Created'),
                'type' => 'datetime',
                'filter_index' => 'rt.created_at',
                'index' => 'review_created_at',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-date col-date-min-width',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-date'
            ]
        );

        if (!$this->_coreRegistry->registry('usePendingFilter')) {
            $this->addColumn(
                'status',
                [
                    'header' => __('Status'),
                    'type' => 'options',
                    'options' => $this->_reviewData->getReviewStatuses(),
                    'filter_index' => 'rt.status_id',
                    'index' => 'status_id'
                ]
            );
        }

        $this->addColumn(
            'title',
            [
                'header' => __('Title'),
                'filter_index' => 'rdt.title',
                'index' => 'title',
                'type' => 'text',
                'truncate' => 50,
                'escape' => true
            ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'nickname',
            [
                'header' => __('Nickname'),
                'filter_index' => 'rdt.nickname',
                'index' => 'nickname',
                'type' => 'text',
                'truncate' => 50,
                'escape' => true,
                'header_css_class' => 'col-name',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-name'
            ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'detail',
            [
                'header' => __('Review'),
                'index' => 'detail',
                'filter_index' => 'rdt.detail',
                'type' => 'text',
                'truncate' => 50,
                'nl2br' => true,
                'escape' => true
            ]
        );

        /**
         * Check is single store mode
         */
        if (!$this->_storeManager->isSingleStoreMode()) {
            $this->addColumn(
                'visible_in',
                [
                    'header' => __('Visibility'),
                    'index' => 'stores',
                    'type' => 'store',
                    'store_view' => true,
                    'sortable' => false
                ]
            );
        }

        $this->addColumn(
            'type',
            [
                'header' => __('Type'),
                'type' => 'select',
                'index' => 'type',
                'filter' => \Magento\Review\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\Filter\Type::class,
                'renderer' => \Magento\Review\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\Renderer\Type::class
            ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'name',
            ['header' => __('Product'), 'type' => 'text', 'index' => 'name', 'escape' => true]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'sku',
            [
                'header' => __('SKU'),
                'type' => 'text',
                'index' => 'sku',
                'escape' => true
            ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'action',
            [
                'header' => __('Action'),
                'type' => 'action',
                'getter' => 'getReviewId',
                'actions' => [
                    [
                        'caption' => __('Edit'),
                        'url' => [
                            'base' => 'review/product/edit',
                            'params' => [
                                'productId' => $this->getProductId(),
                                'customerId' => $this->getCustomerId(),
                                'ret' => $this->_coreRegistry->registry('usePendingFilter') ? 'pending' : null,
                            ],
                        ],
                        'field' => 'id',
                    ],
                ],
                'filter' => false,
                'sortable' => false
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'customer_id',
            [
                'header' => __('Customer Emails'),
                'type' => 'text',
                'index' => 'customer_id',
                'renderer' => 'Vendor\CustomReview\Block\Adminhtml\Customer\Grid\Renderer\CustomerEmails',
                'escape' => true
            ]
        );

        $block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('grid.bottom.links');
        if ($block) {
            $this->setChild('grid.bottom.links', $block);
        }
        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', __('CSV'));

        return $this;
    }

}
```