# How to show yes/no text for boolean field in custom added grid column

Tags: magento2.4

Magento 2.4

I have added a custom column to an admin grid through a Observer class with following code. The field relevant to the column is a Boolean field and so the new column appears with values 1 , 0 or empty (in case that field hasnt get updated before) like in the screenshot below. I need to show text 'Yes' for 1, 'No' for 0 & for 'empty' . Is that something can be done along with this Observer or do I have to go for an alternative appraoch.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

class AddPromotionColumnToCategoryGridObserver implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\Product */
        $grid = $observer->getGrid();

        if($grid && $grid instanceof \Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\Product) {
            $grid->addColumnAfter(
                'promotion_on',
                [
                    'header' => __('Promotion On'),
                    'index' => 'promotion_on'],
                'sku'
            );
            $grid->sortColumnsByOrder();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Thanks and Best Regards

Indunil

Comment: You can do it using custom renderer, try this reference https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/183246/84221

Comment: You can do the same with ui_component by creating your_ui_grid.xml and also you can define ui_component listing values in 
 public function YourOptionName()
    {
        return [
            ['value' => 1, 'label' => __('Yes')],
            ['value' => 0, 'label' => __('No')]
        ];
    }

Comment: Thanks @RahulBarot  . I ll try that out.

Comment: Thanks @Oscprofessionals too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add **renderer** to column properties and create a renderer class for it.

Change

```
$grid->addColumnAfter(
    'promotion_on',
    [
        'header' => __('Promotion On'),
        'index' => 'promotion_on'],
    'sku'
);
```

to

```
$grid->addColumnAfter(
    'promotion_on',
    [
        'header' => __('Promotion On'),
        'index' => 'promotion_on',
        'renderer' => \Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\Product\Renderer\PromotionOn::class
    ],
    'sku'
);
```

Create a renderer class for your column:
File path: app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Category/Tab/Product/Renderer/PromotionOn.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\Product\Renderer;

class PromotionOn extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\AbstractRenderer
{
    public function render(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $row)
    {
        return !$row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex()) ? __('No') : __('Yes');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed explanation.

Comment: @IndunilRamadasa Does my answer help you resolve your issue? If so, please mark it as accepted. That indicates your issue is solved and helps others with the same issue find out the verified answer easily.

Comment: Yes Indeed it helped me.  Thanks a lot. Sorry about late response........

Comment: No worries, at least you still confirm it works. Cheers!